# Tomcat Connection Pool Connection has already been closed

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-pooling

In our application, we have configured database connection pools using Tomcat DBCP. Our application has more than 150 databases. We can't set the max active connections for a pool more than 2. Because our server resources are limited. While performance test execution with 100 users, some requests failed by throwing the following error randomly. So I would like to know if there is a way that we can fine tune the pool configurations to resolve this issue.

Data Source Configurations in Tomcat's server.xml

```
<!-- Data Source -->
<Resource name="jdbc/openedge/xxxxx/services/xxxx" auth="Container"
    factory="main.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver"
    url="jdbc:datadirect:openedge://xxxxx"
    username="xxxxxx" 
    password="xxxxxx" 
    initialSize="2" 
    maxActive="2"
    maxIdle="2" 
    minIdle="2" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="900" 
    logAbandoned="true"
    global="jdbc/openedge/xxxxx/services/xxxx" 
    maxWait="-1" 
    testOnBorrow="true"
    validationInterval="30000" 
    validatorClassName="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.util.DBConnectionValidator" 
    validationTimeout="2"  />
```

Error Stack

```
<SSS-MAT-61771>  2014/Oct/01 10:07:32,599 WARN  [SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
<SSS-MAT-61771>  2014/Oct/01 10:07:32,599 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] Connection has already been  closed.
<SSS-MAT-61771>  2014/Oct/01 10:07:32,599 INFO  [BaseDaoImpl] closeSession starting:        BBBCompositeDaoImpl
<SSS-MAT-61771>  2014/Oct/01 10:07:32,599 INFO  [BaseDaoImpl] closeSession completed: BBBCompositeDaoImpl
<SSS-MAT-61771>  2014/Oct/01 10:07:32,599 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Internal server error
main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.common.exception.DataServiceException: Internal server error
    at     main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.services.ManageAssetsRestImpl.getMethodInManageAssests(Unknown     Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.filter.LogFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
    at     org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterNonTransactionalQuery(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:598)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1790)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
    at main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.common.dao.impl.BBBCompositeDaoImpl.getBBBIds(Unknown Source)
    at main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.business.delegates.ManageAssetsDelegate.getBBBIdentifiers(Unknown Source)
    at main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.business.delegates.ManageAssetsDelegate.getBBBIds(Unknown Source)
    at main.java.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.services.ManageAssetsRestImpl.getBBBIds(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:117)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at $Proxy166.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:392)
    ... 49 more
```

Hibernate Configurations for routing databases at runtime.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd"
 default-lazy-init="true" default-autowire="byName">

<bean id="bxxHistoryDao"
    class="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.common.dao.impl.bxxHistoryDaoImpl"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="bxxSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="bxxDataSource"
    class="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxdataservices.openedge.BaseRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="AXXXX" value-ref="bxxDataSource_AXXXX" />
            <entry key="EXXXX" value-ref="bxxDataSource_EXXXX" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="bxxDataSource_AXXXX"
    class="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxdataservices.openedge.BxxRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="BXXX1" value-ref="BXXX1DataSource_AXXXX" />
            <entry key="BXXX2" value-ref="BXXX2DataSource_AXXXX" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="bxxDataSource_EXXXX"
    class="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxdataservices.openedge.BxxRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="BXXX1" value-ref="BXXX1DataSource_EXXXX" />
            <entry key="BXXX2" value-ref="BXXX2DataSource_EXXXX" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="parentDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    abstract="true" />
<bean id="BXXX1DataSource_AXXXX" parent="parentDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="java:comp/env/jdbc/openedge/BXXX1/rmservices/AXXXX" />
</bean>
<bean id="BXXX2DataSource_AXXXX" parent="parentDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="java:comp/env/jdbc/openedge/BXXX2/rmservices/AXXXX" />
</bean>
<bean id="BXXX1DataSource_EXXXX" parent="parentDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="java:comp/env/jdbc/openedge/BXXX1/rmservices/EXXXX" />
</bean>
<bean id="BXXX2DataSource_EXXXX" parent="parentDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName"
        value="java:comp/env/jdbc/openedge/BXXX2/rmservices/EXXXX" />
</bean>

<bean id="parentSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.ProgressDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bxxSessionFactory" parent="parentSessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="bxxDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="main.java.com.xxxxxxxx.common.domain.box" />
</bean>

<bean id="bxxTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="bxxSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="bxxTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: is it possible you have code that retrieves a connection from the pool and explicitly calls close() on it?

Comment: We use HibernateDaoSupport in our application and we would like to keep it. 
You are suggesting to get the connection manually from the pool as below and close it after using it. right?

Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
Connection actual =((javax.sql.PooledConnection)con).getConnection();

Comment: What is your spring configuration? How do you attach this connection pool to Spring? You should not maintain these connections nor close them, because everything shall be maintained by HibernateDaoSupport.

Comment: Updated the question with hibernate configurations.
Please refer the updated question.

Comment: Try increasing removeAbandonedTimeout.